# Raspberry pi and arduino CAN bus communication not working

Tags: c, arduino, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4, can-bus

So I am working on a project to establish CAN bus communication between raspberry pi 4 and arduino. Unfortunately, I don't have great success. So I already established connection between multiples raspberry pies and it is working perfectly. So to configure my raspberry pi I followed the steps of online tutorial. I added this lines in the /boot/config.txt:

```
dtoverlay=mcp2515-can0,oscillator=8000000,interupt=12
dtoverlay=spi-bcm2835-overlay
```

installed the can utilities and initiate the can using

```
sudo ip link set can0 up type can bitrate 500000
```

After that I created python code to control the receiving and sending of data to the CAN bus. Here is my code for sending data:

```
import time
import can

bustype = 'socketcan'
channel = 'can0'
bus = can.interface.Bus(channel=channel, bustype=bustype,bitrate=500000)

while True:
   msg = can.Message(arbitration_id=2, data=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], is_extended_id=False)
   bus.send(msg)
   time.sleep(0.1)
</code></pre>
```

and here's is the one for receiving:

```
import time
import can
```

```
bustype = 'socketcan'
channel = 'can0'
bus = can.interface.Bus(channel=channel, bustype=bustype,bitrate=500000)

while True:
   print(bus.recv())
   time.sleep(0.1)
```

So for the arduino part I tried using UNO and Mega2560.
My connection on both boards is the same:

```
VCC --> 5V
GND --> GND
CS  --> pin 10
SO  --> pin12
SI  --> pin11
SCK --> pin 13
INT --> pin 2
```

Tried multiple libraries on of them https://github.com/Seeed-Studio/Seeed_Arduino_CAN/blob/master/examples/recv_sd/recv_sd.ino
and the https://www.arduinolibraries.info/libraries/can. So I uploaded the example code to the arduino. Here it is:

```
    
    #include 
    
    void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    while (!Serial);
    
    Serial.println("CAN Sender");
    
    // start the CAN bus at 500 kbps
    //  if (!CAN.begin(500E3)) {
    //    Serial.println("Starting CAN failed!");
    //    while (1);
    //  }
    }
    
    void loop() {
    // send packet: id is 11 bits, packet can contain up to 8 bytes of data
    Serial.print("Sending packet ... ");
    
    CAN.beginPacket(0x12);
    CAN.write('h');
    CAN.write('e');
    CAN.write('l');
    CAN.write('l');
    CAN.write('o');
    CAN.endPacket();
    
    Serial.println("done");
    
    delay(1000);
    
    // send extended packet: id is 29 bits, packet can contain up to 8 bytes of data
    Serial.print("Sending extended packet ... ");
    
    CAN.beginExtendedPacket(0xabcdef);
    CAN.write('w');
    CAN.write('o');
    CAN.write('r');
    CAN.write('l');
    CAN.write('d');
    CAN.endPacket();
    
    Serial.println("done");
    
    delay(1000);
    }
```

and when i upload it to the Arduino Uno it gives "Starting CAN failed!", but on the Arduino Mega everything seems to work fine, but both times no data is received by the raspberry pi no matter if i use the python code or simple "candump can0" command. Tried it even with the receiving example :

```
    #include 
    
    void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    while (!Serial);
    
    Serial.println("CAN Receiver");
    
    // start the CAN bus at 500 kbps
    if (!CAN.begin(500E3)) {
      Serial.println("Starting CAN failed!");
    while (1);
    }
    }
    
    void loop() {
    // try to parse packet
    int packetSize = CAN.parsePacket();
    
    if (packetSize || CAN.packetId() != -1) {
      // received a packet
      Serial.print("Received ");
    
    if (CAN.packetExtended()) {
      Serial.print("extended ");
    }
    
    if (CAN.packetRtr()) {
      // Remote transmission request, packet contains no data
      Serial.print("RTR ");
    }
    
    Serial.print("packet with id 0x");
    Serial.print(CAN.packetId(), HEX);
    
    if (CAN.packetRtr()) {
      Serial.print(" and requested length ");
      Serial.println(CAN.packetDlc());
    } else {
      Serial.print(" and length ");
      Serial.println(packetSize);
    
      // only print packet data for non-RTR packets
      while (CAN.available()) {
        Serial.print((char)CAN.read());
      }
      Serial.println();
    }
    
    Serial.println();
    }
    }
```

So I will greatly appreciate help from anybody, because I have struggled with this problem for the last 2 weeks and I really want to solve it. Thank you for your time

Comment: `CAN.begin(500E3))` This is a floating point constant. It doesn't make the slightest sense. Does that lib really require you to pass on floating point parameters? If so get a better lib. If not, pay attention to compiler warnings.

Comment: I used the example code that the library CAN provided, I will try this change, but I don't think this is the problem.

Comment: It is definitely _a_ problem, since it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: changed it from 500E3 to 500000 and that didn't resolve the problem

Comment: `#include` is obviously nonsense. Maybe you could post the actual code used when compiling, instead of some pseudo code...

Comment: it's not just #include, in the code it is "#include <CAN.h>", but when i added it in stack oveflow it removes the <CAN.h>

Answer (score 0):

So I have finally found a solution. I guess the other libraries had some problem sending data, cause I set everything with the same configuration. However, today I found this library->https://www.arduinolibraries.info/libraries/mcp_can, which helped me program correctly the arduino and it works perfectly in connection with another arduino or raspberry pi.